# Get or else insert in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of objects with columns for a number of properties and a column with a unique, SERIAL identifier.

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE person(
   id SERIAL NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
   age INT NOT NULL,
   can_drive BOOL NOT NULL
)
```

Now, is it possible to write a single query, which checks to see if an entry ( eg: Fred, 27, true) is in the table, and if it is, returns the id, else inserts the entry and returns the new id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
t=# with i as (
  insert into person (name,age,can_drive)
  select 'Fred',27,true
  where not exists (
    select 0 from person where name = 'Fred' and age= 27 and can_drive
  )
  returning id
)
select * from i
union all
select id from person  where name = 'Fred' and age= 27 and can_drive;
 id
----
  1
(1 row)
```